# returning results from a function while making it applicable in an if

Tags: bash

I want to set a variable value in a function, but also be able to use it in an if.
the args array is arguments applied when running the bash script `args=("$@")`.

```
containsfilepath () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:1}"; do [[ "$e" =~ .*".out" ]] && return 0 && local $path="abc"; done
  return 1
}
```

so I can do this

```
if containsfilepath "${args[@]}" ; then 

    echo "$path" "\n"
fi
```

I have made the code but it's not working any ideas?

Comment: This is a pure programming question and belongs on Stack Overflow instead of here, I believe.

Comment: I guess you maybe right, But I've got the idea people here are much better experts in bash script.

Comment: Mmm... nope, not really.  Most of the Bash help I see is from SO

Comment: Most bash questions are on-topic here, since it is an integral part of Ubuntu, but [so] might be a better place to ask in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra dollar sign in the local path statement.  Try this:

```
containsfilepath () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:1}"; do [[ "$e" =~ .*".out" ]] && return 0 && local path="abc"; done
  return 1
}
```

In this code, because the `return 0` statement is executed *before* the `path` assignment statement is reached, `path` is never assigned a value.  If you want to have path assigned to a value that can be accessed later, the statements need to be reversed and the `local` qualifier needs to be removed. try:

```
containsfilepath () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:1}"
  do
      [[ "$e" =~ .*".out" ]] && { path="abc"; return 0; }
  done
  return 1
}
```

Comment: still the same $path come out empty! :(

Comment: I updated the answer with code that changes that: `path` is assigned a value and it is no longer local.

Comment: @adonis OK.  Answer updated with new phrasing.